# Cherry framework - Overriding function in template-general.php

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress Cherry framework, I am trying to edit `template-general.php` file functions, but it's different not able to do so. I tried to follow [**this link**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-overriding-parent-theme-functions-in-your-child-theme--cms-22623),
but does not help.

[**Link for Cherry framework**](http://www.cherryframework.com/) to download   file structure is: `cherryframework4\lib\functions\template-general.php`

I am trying to override below function:

```
function cherry_get_site_logo( $location = 'header' ) {
    $logo_class = array();

    switch ( $location ) {
        case 'header':
            $type         = cherry_get_option( 'logo-type', 'text' );
            $logo_img_ids = cherry_get_option( 'logo-image-path', false );
            $tag          = is_front_page() ? 'h1' : 'h2';
            $logo_class[] = 'site-title';
            $logo_class[] = $type . '-logo';
            $link_class   = '';
            break;

        case 'footer':
            $type         = cherry_get_option( 'footer-logo-type', 'text' );
            $logo_img_ids = cherry_get_option( 'footer-logo-image-path', false );
            $tag          = 'div';
            $logo_class[] = 'cherry-footer-logo';
            $logo_class[] = $type . '-logo';
            $link_class   = 'footer-logo-link';
            break;

        default:
            $tag          = 'div';
            $logo_class[] = $location . '-logo';
            $link_class   = '';
            break;
    }

    $logo_class = apply_filters( 'cherry_logo_classes', $logo_class, $location );
    $logo_class = array_unique( $logo_class );
    $logo_class = array_map( 'sanitize_html_class', $logo_class );

    if ( 'image' == $type && false != $logo_img_ids ) {

        $images = explode( ',', $logo_img_ids );

        if ( count( $images ) > 1 ) {
            $logo_content = cherry_get_retina_logo( $images );
        } else {

            $img = wp_get_attachment_url( $images[0] );

            $logo_image_format = apply_filters(
                'cherry_logo_image_format',
                '<a href="%1$s" rel="home"><img src="%2$s" alt="%3$s"></a>',
                $location
            );

            $logo_content = sprintf( $logo_image_format, home_url( '/' ), esc_url( $img ), get_bloginfo( 'title' ) );
        }

    } else {
        $logo_content = cherry_get_site_link( $link_class );
    }

    $logo = $logo_content ? sprintf( '<%3$s class="%1$s">%2$s</%3$s>', join( ' ', $logo_class ), $logo_content, $tag ) : '';

    return apply_filters( 'cherry_get_site_logo', $logo, $location );
}
```

Anyone come across this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No answers? Well here is a suggestion:

in functions.php of your child or custom theme

```
    <?php

    add_filter('cherry_get_site_logo', 'your_get_site_logo');

    function your_get_site_logo($logo, $location){
      $output = '';

      // your function logic

      return $output;
    }
```

be aware that this will affect all locations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...sorry i didnt update the answer i got from wp development - > link ->http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/226159/cherry-framework-overriding-function-in-template-general-php